# Foursquare Checkin in delivery restaurants

Tags: foursquare

I have an app where you can buy food on delivery restaurants.

Can I use the Foursquare API so the user can check-in on the restaurant that he order from?
Probably the user will not be in the resutaurant it self when he checkin.

There is an special way to do this on the foursquare api?

thanks

Comment: I really don't understand why the negative points.. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check-in any user that has authorized your application at a venue using the [/checkins/add](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/checkins/add.html) endpoint in the API. If you don't know the user's actual location (or fully expect them not to actually be there, but have a legitimate reason to be checking in, e.g. for delivery) be sure to leave the lat/lng parameter blank. The check-in will go through and be in the user's history, but won't count for badges/mayorships, etc.

Comment: Thanks!, I think I could live with that. Although I cannot find any reference for that in the foursquare documentation. Where did you get that info?

Comment: The /checkins/add documentation mentions "Only specify [lat,lng] if you have a GPS or other device reported location for the user at the time of check-in." We've commented on the implications of this in our old forum... we should add some clarification on the endpoint docs.

Comment: that would be great. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too sure what you're asking. I don't think you can check in to places if you're not even near them (or at least I wasn't able to when I last used the 4sq API).

Check [this](http://ryokuweil.wordpress.com/2011/08/29/how-to-use-the-foursquare-api-v2-with-oauth-and-php/) tutorial out if you need help getting started with the API, or read the 4sq api documentation.